# Access vba to count two field with criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have a table like this,

```
   SAP   SAG 
   One   One        
   One   Two
   One   One        
   One   Two 
   One   Two
```

I want to generate a table which shows, how many One X One and how many One X Two like below, in VBA or through Query, I googled it, but i couldn't find
Any suggestions ?

```
     SAG    
SAP  One    Two
One   2      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a standard pivot query, pivoting on the `SAP` column.  Note in the query below that we use Access' `IIF()` function.  `IIF()` in Access is analogous to the `CASE` expression in most other flavors of SQL.

```
SELECT
    SAP,
    SUM(IIF(SAG = 'One', 1, 0)) AS [One],
    SUM(IIF(SAG = 'Two', 1, 0)) AS [Two]
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    SAP
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are after:

```
Select
    SAP,
    Abs(Sum([SAP]=[SAG])) As [One],
    Abs(Sum([SAP]<>[SAG])) As [Two]
From 
    YourTable
Group By
    SAP
```